# Приостановить или отменить событие change()

Tags: jquery, form

Сделал форму фильтра, которая отправлет запрос php обарботчику каждый рах когда пользователь что-то меняет на форме (ставит галочку в чекбокс, меняет диапазон цен). Для реализации такого поведения привязал отпавку данных формы на событие change() на всех полях формы, как-то так:

```js
$('form input').each(function(){

   $(this).change(function(){
     
     /*Отпаравляем данные формы обработчику*/
     formaSubmit()
   });

});
```

Теперь появилась задачка сделать кнопку "Сброса" формы, без перезагрузки страницы. Я сделал так:

```js
/*перебрал все чекбоксы и с каждым сделал так:*/
 $(this).removeAttr("checked");
 $(this).change();
/*т.е. удалил флажёк и вызвал change(), если  не вызвать change(), галочка как-бы останется стоять и при отправке данных формы будут отправляться "отжатые" чекбоксы */

/*Перебрал все слайдеры (цена, размер, вес) и слеоао так*/
  $(this).val($(this).attr("data-max-value")).change();
/*тут аналогично, поставил слайдер в исходное положение (указал исходное значение) и вызвал change(), чтобы "бегунок стал согласно значению в input"*/
```

Но на change() у меня висит отправка данных формы, вот и получается отправка в цыкле. Всё тормозит и глючит. Как выйти из положения с минимальными временными затратами на переделку кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписать эту жуть...

> ```
> $('form input').each(function(){
>   $(this).change(function(){
> ```

Зачем `each`, когда можно сразу `change`?
А ещё лучше использовать всплытие и подписаться

```
$('form').on('change', 'input', function() { ... });
```

> ```
> $(this).removeAttr("checked");
> ```

Это вообще работает только один раз. Надо убирать чекнуточть через

```
$(this).prop("checked", false);
```

Опять же, зачем проходить по всем, если jQuery это может сделать сам?

> ```
> $(this).change();
> ```

А это вообще зачем? Ну поменялось состояние флажка и что?
Или там какой-то плагин для чекбоксов сделан?

> ```
> $(this).val($(this).attr("data-max-value")).change();
> ```

Насколько я помню, слайдер умеет менять значение без вызова change.

И кончай постоянно оборачивать this. Есть переменные.

> Но на change() у меня висит отправка данных формы, вот и получается отправка в цыкле.

Вариант 1. Отписаться от события. Для этого можно сохранить функцию или использовать неймспейс события - второй вариант лучше, первый у меня глючил. Да и удобнее второй. Этот вариант подходит, если перестраивается вся форма. На твой случай не похоже.

Вариант 2. Сохранить в переменной или data-атрибуте флаг, что сейчас идёт сброс формы. Флаг проверить в обработчике.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так?

```
//давайте заведем флаг
var justCleaningUp; 

//и поставим его в ТРУ перед очисткой формы
function CleanFormReset() {
    justCleaningUp = true;
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).change();
    $(this).val($(this).attr("data-max-value")).change();
    //а потом обратно в НЕ-ТРУ
    justCleaningUp = false;
}
```

Ну и проверяем флаг перед отправкой:

```
  $('form input').each(function(){

       $(this).change(function(){
         if (!justCleaningUp) {
           /*Отпаравляем данные формы обработчику*/
           formaSubmit()
         } else {
           //ничего не делаем, просто форму почистили
         }
       });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

А разве не получится просто убрать `$(this).change();` и в конце функции сброса формы вызвать `formaSubmit();`